# Because of registerEnumType, it cannot be tested in the jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typegraphql

I'm using typegraphql, and i register DayOfWeek enum type using resgiterEnumType.

following is my enum and registerEnumType function, and they are in one file.

```
export enum DayOfWeek {
    SUNDAY,
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY
}

registerEnumType(DayOfWeek, {
    name: "DayOfWeekType", // this one is mandatory
});
```

It works well when i run program. but when i run jest test I got an message like following

```
Looks like you've forgot to provide experimental metadata API polyfill.
  12 | }
  13 | 
> 14 | registerEnumType(DayOfWeek, {
     | ^
  15 |     name: "DayOfWeekType", // this one is mandatory
  16 | });
  17 |
```

If i put enum and registerEnumType in the same file, run works well and test is failed.

and If i separate enum and registerEnumType, graphql not found DayOfWeek type....

how can i solved that?

Comment: Do you have `import "reflect-metadata";` at the top of your test suite file?

Comment: did you get solution to this problem? I'm getting same problem

Answer (score 14):

You need to add

```
import "reflect-metadata";
```

at the top of your file

Comment: AND [the docs](https://typegraphql.com/docs/installation.html) say "We must ensure that it is imported at the top of our entry file (before we use/import type-graphql or our resolvers):" So be careful with how you organizing your imports.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';

describe('your test suite', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [
                GraphQLModule.forRoot({
                    ... 
                }),
            ],
        }).compile();

    });
});
```

You need to provision `GraphQLModule` in your spec.

P/S: the code-snippet above is under assumption that you're on `NestJS` framework.